# Laravel two 404 styles

Tags: php, laravel

I have a main site and an admin control panel.

I want to have different 404 pages for each version.

How should I do this? I currently have the following code in my `app/Exceptions/Handles.php` file:

```
/**
    * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
    * @param  \Exception  $exception
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    */
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if($exception instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException)
    {
        $view = $request->is('admin/*') ? 'acp.errors.404' : 'errors.404' ;

        return response()->view($view, [], 404);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

But I use the package [`spatie/laravel-permission`](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) and get the following error;

```
Trying to get property 'role' of non-object (View: F:\Development\RPR\site\resources\views\layouts\acp.blade.php) (View: F:\Development\RPR\site\resources\views\layouts\acp.blade.php)
```

I use in `acp.blade.php` `auth()->user()->role`, to get the user role, which just works fine without any exception. How should I fix this?

Comment: Exception handlers/middleware and the use of packages is tricky. The why is in the bootingprocess of laravel itself. Resolve this in the `errors.404` file where you can include the page you want. That is the simplest solution. It will still work with future releases of laravel versions.

Comment: @DimitriMostrey What do you mean by that? It's like the auth that is not working with the packages.... I don't see the solution here?

Comment: Let a 404 pass up to the view request lifecycle. There you can determine which 404 to show by checking the `Auth::user()` information. I've learned what can be avoided being a middleware, it's better to follow that course. A 404 probability is too slim to middleware it.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ways to accomplish different 404 views depending on the route. Both will allow you to have these error pages:

```
/resources/views/acp/errors/404.blade.php
/resources/views/errors/404.blade.php
```

The directories will be checked in order until a view is found, which means you can selectively add custom error views and fall through to the default when none exist. If the route did not match, then it will not look for a custom error page.

#### Option 1

Override `registerErrorViewPaths()` inside `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`:

```php
/**
 * Register the error template hint paths.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function registerErrorViewPaths()
{
    parent::registerErrorViewPaths();

    if (request()->is('admin/*')) {
        View::prependNamespace(
            'errors',
            realpath(base_path('resources/views/acp/errors'))
        );
    }
}
```

#### Option 2

Create a ViewServiceProvider:

```sh
php artisan make:provider ViewServiceProvider
```

Register your provider in `config/app.php`:

```php
'providers' => [
    // ...

    App\Providers\ViewServiceProvider::class,
],
```

Edit the boot method of your provider:

```php
/**
 * Bootstrap services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    if (request()->is('admin/*')) {
        View::prependNamespace(
            'errors',
            realpath(base_path('resources/views/acp/errors'))
        );
    }
}
```

---

For the second part of the question, `auth()->user()` is only available when the session middleware has run. If the 404 was caused by the route not existing, then the request does not go through the web middleware and unfortunately sessions and auth information will not be available. However, if the 404 was caused by a `ModelNotFoundException` triggered inside a controller, then the web middleware probably *did* run and you can access the user.

Inside your error view you have to check if the user is signed in:

```html
@guest
    <p>Hello, guest</p>
@else
    <p>Hello, {{ auth()->user()->name }}</p>
@endguest
```

If this is not good enough for your use case, then you might want to try [Route::fallback()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#fallback-routes), which allows you to define a controller for serving 404 pages and *does* run web middleware.

Comment: And would it be possible to have the authenticated user in that view? that would be awesome

Comment: @Robin see the part about `Route::fallback()` at the end of the answer